# No candidates found for method call javafx (intelliJ build.gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to construct a Java application using the JavaFX GUI Framework with the Gradle build tool. I run `gradle run` on the terminal and I get no errors, however when I highlight over the javafx section on line 47, I get a message saying: "No candidates found for method call javafx".

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

group 'com.micharski.jerseytraffic'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

def javaFXPlatform = getJavaFXPlatform()
def javaFXVersion = "11.0.2"

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-base:${javaFXVersion}:${javaFXPlatform}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:${javaFXVersion}:${javaFXPlatform}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:${javaFXVersion}:${javaFXPlatform}"
}

java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

private static String getJavaFXPlatform() {
    def currentOS = org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem;
    if (currentOS.isWindows()) {
        return 'win'
    } else if (currentOS.isLinux()) {
        return 'linux'
    } else if (currentOS.isMacOsX()) {
        return 'mac'
    }
    return null
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
    version = '11.0.2'
    mainClassName = 'com.micharski.jerseytraffic.Driver'
}
```

As well as that, my JavaFX import to my Driver class is not working either:

```java
package com.micharski.jerseytraffic;

import org.openjfx.javafxplugin.*; //Error here: Cannot resolve symbol

public class Driver extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); //Error here: Cannot resolve method
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){ //Error here: Cannot resolve symbol

    }
}
```

Comment: The `import org.openjfx.javafxplugin.*` looks wrong. That package would seem to belong to the JavaFX Gradle _plugin_, not JavaFX itself. Are you sure you don't mean to import `javafx.application.Application` (and `javafx.stage.Stage`)?

Comment: Have you tried following the **Modular with Gradle** section here https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ ?